# How to keep 2 SESSIONS going at the same time? if it is possible PHP

Tags: php, session, phpmyadmin

I have created a user sign in page where the user signs in to the database with their name and password (DBname =signin, table=information) i want to keep the session going so no matter what page the user goes on to is displays "HELLO and the username)". So far this works perfectly.

When going on to the page to AddRental (only the address information) i have to create a new database connection and session to DB=project and table=address. But for some reason it brings up an error near line2 the SESSION_START();

I think i need to keep 2 sessions going at once but i cant find out how to do so. Does anyone have any suggestions?

many thanks

```
<?php
session_start();

    $hostname="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="root"; // phpmyadmin username 
    $password=""; // phpmyadmin password 
    $dbname="project"; // Database name 
    $tblname="address"; // Table name

    // Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$hostname", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$dbname")or die("cannot select DB");


    // If form not yet submitted display form
    // To check if the Submit button was clicked
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        // Get data entered into into form fields
        $PostCode = $_POST['PostCode'];
        $AddL1 = $_POST['AddL1'];
        $AddL2 = $_POST['AddL2'];
        $AddL3 = $_POST['AddL3'];
        $County = $_POST['County'];
        $Country = $_POST['Country'];   


        // Validation of the data entered into into form fields
        //if ((preg_match('/^([A-Za-z]+ ?)*$/', $name)) 
        //&& (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+([\.\-\+]{0,1}[A-Za-z0-9_])*@[A-Za-z0-9_]+([\.-]{0,1}[A-Za-z0-9_]+)*(\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2,4})+$/', $email))
        //&& (preg_match('/^[A-Z][A-Z]/', $country)) 
        //&& (preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s)/', $password)))
        {           
            // Insert data taken form fields into table
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `address` (`PostCode`, `AddL1`, `AddL2`, `AddL3`,`County`,`Country`)
            VALUES('$PostCode', '$AddL1', '$AddL2', '$AddL3', 'County','Country'") or die(mysql_error());
        }   
    }   
    // Close connection to database server
//  mysql_close($mysql_connect);
?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title> Menu Form </title>
<link rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AddRental.css"/>
</head><body>

<div id="logo">
<img src="C:/Users/Daisy/Desktop/Website/Forms/FC.JPG"  width="30%" height="5%"/>
<div id="addr"> Add Rental </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id ="rform"> Insert Address
    <br>    
<FORM action = "AddRental.php" method="post">
            <label for="PostCode">PostCode</label>
            <input type="text" name="PostCode" id="PostCode" value="" maxlength="8" />
            <br>
            <label for="AddL1">AddL1</label>
            <input type="text" name="AddL1" id="AddL1" value="" maxlength="40" />
            <br>
            <label for="AddL2">AddL2</label>
            <input type="text" name="AddL2" id="AddL2" value="" maxlength="25" />
            <br>
            <label for="AddL3">AddL3</label>
            <input type="text" name="AddL3" id="AddL3" value="" maxlength="25" />
            <br>
            <label for="County">County</label>
            <input type="text" name="County" id="County" value="" maxlength="20" />
            <br>
            <label for="Country">Country</label>
            <input type="text" name="Country" id="Country" value="" maxlength="20" />
            <br>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" >SUBMIT</button></div>

</FORM>

    <div id ="lilmenu"> <?php echo "Hello ".$_SESSION['myusername']; ?>
    <br>Options <br>

        <FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="Welcome.php">
            <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Back"></FORM><br>
        <FORM name="LogOut" method="post" action="logout.php">
            <INPUT name="LogOut" TYPE="submit" VALUE="Log-Out"></FORM>
    </div>
</div>



<div id="footer"> &copy; Copyright 2014 </div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: session state and database connections have little to do with one another.

Comment: You do not need a new user session to open a connection to a different database. You can use [link identifiers](http://uk3.php.net/mysql_connect) when you connect to query one or the other database. Secondly this code is using the deprecated mysql_* functions, if at all possible you should be looking to change to either mysqli_* functions or PDO as the mysql_* functions will be removed from a future version of PHP

Comment: The error displayed is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2"

Comment: ok thank you i will give it a go with mysqi or PDO

Comment: @DaisyT-g This is not due to session. This is a sql error

Comment: Missing `$` for two of your values in `('$PostCode', '$AddL1', '$AddL2', '$AddL3', 'County','Country'")` so try with `('$PostCode', '$AddL1', '$AddL2', '$AddL3', '$County','$Country'")` @DaisyT-g

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, you're getting `"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2"` which is caused by your sql query not the session.

I don't support `mysql_*` functions but as you're using it, please confirm you sanitize the input before using with `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Otherwise special characters like `'` or `"` in your input can cause errors in your SQL query.